# insert column from one table to another, update if exists in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
  Table_A
+----------+-----------------------------+
| Table_ID | Unique                      |
| column1  |                             |
| column2  |                             |
| records  | Auto increment| Primary Key |
+----------+-----------------------------+

CREATE TABLE `Table_A` (
      `records` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `column1` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      `column2` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Table_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`records`),
      UNIQUE KEY `table_ID_UNIQUE` (`Table_ID`)
) 

  Table_B 
+----------+-----------------------------+
| Table_ID | Unique                      |
| column1  |                             |
| records  | Auto increment| Primary Key |
+----------+-----------------------------+
```

I need to insert `column1` from `Table_B` into `Table_A` or update if `Table_ID` match.

Note that `records` have no relation at all between tables

Any help please?

Comment: can you show us the output of: show create table Table_A; and same for Table_B. I am not following your key definitions. There are couple of ways to achieve this, but if you provide your actual tables it will be easier to explain the answer.

Comment: There... I edited my question. Table_B has the same structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this using two back to back statements, the first one inserts the data if it is not there, the second updates the data (which will duplicate the work if you just inserted but it does not hurt). As in this code below:

```html
insert into Table_A(Table_ID, column1) select Table_ID, column1 from Table_B where not exists (select * from Table_A where Table_ID=Table_B.Table_ID);

update Table_A
inner join Table_B 
on Table_A.Table_ID=Table_B.Table_ID
set Table_A.column1=Table_B.column1;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Got this error with your code: Error Code: 1221. Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT. The first statement works tho.

Comment: i updated the answer, you can remove the limit. I was trying to be conservative, but you do not have a specific ID to start with so that was not correct. Any how, the updated answer should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a feature of MySQL `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Please refer to the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) for more specific implantation requirements, but here is a simple snippet.

```
INSERT INTO table_b (table_id, column1) VALUES (1, '')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE;
```

Comment: Before asking this question I read the same link you provided, but I cant seem to understand. On your example, tell me where are you making mysql to use data from table_A? By the way, in my example, Im trying to insert data from table_B into table_A.